# Run Multiple Main Methods from the same Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I have a large scale java application with 5 Main methods in different classes. I want to run this application as a docker container. From [DockerHub OpenJDK Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk), I started my Dockerfile as follows

```
FROM openjdk:latest
COPY . /usr/src/APP
WORKDIR /usr/src/APP`
```

and I want to add the lines to run the main methods. Without Docker, I run the app using the below lines

```
echo 'Starting App'
nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java .:./App.jar path.to.main.class1  >> 
/path/to/nohup/nohup.out 2>&1 &
nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java .:./App.jar path.to.main.class2  >> 
/path/to/nohup/nohup.out 2>&1 &
nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java .:./App.jar path.to.main.class3  >> 
/path/to/nohup/nohup.out 2>&1 &
nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java .:./App.jar path.to.main.class4  >> 
/path/to/nohup/nohup.out 2>&1 &
nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java .:./App.jar path.to.main.class5  >> 
/path/to/nohup/nohup.out 2>&1 &
echo 'App Started Successfully'`
```

Is it possible to run the above scenario in one docker container? If possible, how can it be done while there can only be one `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` instructions in a Dockerfile ?

Comment: add all to one `.sh` and add this .sh to CMD

Comment: @LinPy Would it differ if I used CMD or ENTRYPOINT in this case ?

Comment: @RandaElBehery. See this other answer for differences between CMD and ENTRYPOINT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile/21564990#21564990

Comment: The Docker docs explain how to do this with a script or using supervisord: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/ . In general I would use `supervisord` rather than a script, as it can monitor and restart services that die.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual answer to "how do I run multiple processes from one image" is to run multiple containers.  Given the Dockerfile you show this is fairly straightforward:

```sh
# Build the image (once)
docker build -t myapp .

# Then run the five containers as background processes
docker run -d --name app1 java .:./App.jar path.to.main.class1
docker run -d --name app2 java .:./App.jar path.to.main.class2
docker run -d --name app3 java .:./App.jar path.to.main.class3
docker run -d --name app4 java .:./App.jar path.to.main.class4
docker run -d --name app5 java .:./App.jar path.to.main.class5
```

Since all of the commands are pretty similar, you could write a script to run them

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Use the first command-line argument as the main class
MAIN_CLASS="$1"
shift

# Can also set JAVA_OPTS, other environment variables, ...

# Run the application
exec java -jar App.jar "path.to.main.$MAIN_CLASS" "$@"
```

copy that into the image

```sh
COPY run_main.sh /usr/local/bin
```

and then when you launch the containers just run that wrapper

```sh
docker run -d --name app1 run_main.sh class1
```